# What exactly does a 10-transistor XOR gate look like?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, computers, digital-communications, programmable-logic

I need a schematic for a 10-transistor xor gate, I have searched everywhere and I see 8, 12, 6, but I can't see 10. What does it look like in a transistor like picture?

Comment: Take an 8-transistor OR gate and add two more transistors that don't do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper references a 10T XOR gate:

http://eprints.uthm.edu.my/1716/1/Nabihah_Ahmad_FKEE_(ICEDSA).pdf

The 10T XOR in this paper probably isn't the most straightforward design, though.  It's optimized for low power, and likely makes several tradeoffs.

Comment: The link to the pdf in the answer is no good.

Answer (score 2):

Homework?

What are they trying to teach you?

Look at the various versions and see how they work.
Going from eg 12 to 8 they replace 4 with passives in some manner.
Why did they replace 4?
Could they have just replaced 2?
Could any 2 of 4 have been been replaced
... or just 2
........or 'this 2' or 'that two' but not just any 2 ...?

These are probably exactly the questions that you are meant to be asking yourself and why the question exists.

Try not to just look for finished "answers".
Rather, try to see why the answer is possible and what it teaches you.

IMPORTANT:  The above is a **MUCH BETTER** answer than the one you asked for.
If you do what it suggests you will learn something AND (probably) be pleased when you do so.
If you do not try to answer this sort of question yourself and just go looking for "pictures" that you do not understand then you will fail - maybe the course but more importantly, you will be less successful than you could be.

Answer (score 2):

You take a TG based XNOR:
[image]

That is 4 transistors.

You add two Invertors to generate the complements, /A & /B

so that is an additional 2 X 2 = 4 transistors.

Since this is a XNOR you need to invert the output and that provides a consistent load to the TG's.

That is another 2 transistors.

Voila! 10 transistors

Comment: thanks, i think our professor refuses transmission gates